# React-native Modal Child elements not clickable in IOS 14.3 iphone 12

Tags: ios, react-native, modalviewcontroller

My buttons inside modal is not clickable in iphone 12. it works fine in iphone 12 below models.
Can any one help ?

This is working fine in Android as well as other ios models like iphone  6 , 7 , 8, 10 ,11 but not in iphone 12. When i click button modal will not dismiss. Even entire screen is not clickable.

```
import {Button, Card, Container, Title} from 'native-base';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

export const ModalTesterView = () => {
  const [isModalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(!isModalVisible);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View>
        <Title> Hello</Title>
        <Button bordered onPress={toggleModal}>
          <Text>Show</Text>
        </Button>
        
      </View>
      <Modal
        isVisible={isModalVisible}
        accessibilityViewIsModal={true}
        animationIn="zoomInUp"
        animationOut="zoomOut">
        <Card>
          <View style={{height: 250, backgroundColor: '#FFF'}}>
            <Text>Hello!</Text>

            <Button bordered onPress={toggleModal}>
              <Text>Close</Text>
            </Button>
          </View>
        </Card>
      </Modal>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Comment: After spending several hours, i just uninstalled app from iphone 12 and directly run from Xcode . After that attempt it started working fine. Strange behaviour. :)  I suspect may be due to any npm / react - native caching ...